# Translating strings in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to filter some data based on translated names. What I have tried is

```
filterInput === <Translator getString={item} />
```

Here is my `Translator`:

```
export function Translator({ getString }) {
   const languageContext = useContext(LanguageContext);
    
   return languageContext.dictionary[getString] || getString;
}
```

What I get is the whole object instead of the translated string. How can I get only translated string so I can compare them?

**EDIT:**

Here is object's structure:

```
$$typeof: Symbol(react.element)
key: null
props: {getString: "Vegetables"}
ref: null
type: ƒ Translator({ getString })
_owner: null
_store: {validated: false}
_self: null
_source: {fileName: "...\src\components\common\AutoCompleteBox.js", lineNumber: 14, columnNumber: 19}
__proto__: Object
```

Comment: can you post the structure of object you receive ?

Comment: object's structure above you receive from `return languageContext.dictionary[getString] || getString` right ?

Comment: Yep this is the structure

Comment: can you add `console.log(languageContext.dictionary[getString] || getString)` before return in Translator function ?

Comment: It doesn't log anything. I assume what happening is that it still hasn't reached the return statement so it is still an object instead of simple string. It is actually working whenever is called in component's jsx but not when it is in JS function